# Matplotlib widget in Qt GUI refuses to align multiple axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

If I plot some initial placeholders in Matplotlib so as to not make my GUI entirely empty upon startup, it'll be all misaligned, despite adding a generous amount of `tight_layout`:

[image]

However, if I resize the window just a single pixel...:
[image]

It works! But nobody wants to have to tell the interface to pull itself together before work can commence... So is there any way to fix this problem? It doesn't seem to happen with just raw Matplotlib itself though.

Minimal UI code:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

class WidgetPlot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.canvas = PlotCanvas(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)

class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width = 1, height = 1, dpi = 100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize = (width, height), dpi = dpi, tight_layout = True)
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(131)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(132)
        self.ax3 = self.fig.add_subplot(133)

        self.axes = self.ax1, self.ax2, self.ax3

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)

class Ui_TraceWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, TraceWindow):
        TraceWindow.setObjectName("TraceWindow")
        TraceWindow.resize(1000, 500)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(TraceWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.mpl_LayoutBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.mpl_LayoutBox, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        TraceWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        # Instantiate canvas here
        self.m = WidgetPlot()
        self.canvas = self.m.canvas
        self.mpl_LayoutBox.addWidget(self.m)

        self.drawStuff()

    def drawStuff(self):
        a = np.ndarray(shape = (500, 500))

        for ax in self.canvas.axes:
            ax.clear()
            ax.imshow(a)

        self.canvas.fig.tight_layout()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.fig.tight_layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    TraceWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_TraceWindow()
    ui.setupUi(TraceWindow)
    TraceWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You start off with a really small figure. I would think that if you set something like `width = 6, height = 4`, it should work as expected.